# sys.stdin.readlines() reads nothing from stdin in IPython console (Spyder, Anaconda)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, stdin, spyder

I need to read a text from *stdin* into a python list of words. With the following code program finishes with *lines* as an empty list...

```
from sys import stdin
lines = stdin.readlines()
```

I do not understand where I should insert the text to read it if I work with IPython console.

For example, I need to get the following

> ['She', 'sells', 'sea', 'shells', 'on', 'the', 'sea', 'shore;', 'The', 'shells', 'that', 'she', 'sells', 'are', 'sea', 'shells', "I'm", 'sure.', 'So', 'if', 'she', 'sells', 'sea', 'shells', 'on', 'the', 'sea', 'shore,', "I'm", 'sure', 'that', 'the', 'shells', 'are', 'sea', 'shore', 'shells.']

from the text

> She sells sea shells on the sea shore;
>
> The shells that she sells are sea shells I'm sure.
>
> So if she sells sea shells on the sea shore,
>
> I'm sure that the shells are sea shore shells.

How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you passing that text to the Python script you're running? That's not clear from your question.

Comment: Carlos, I want to pass it through the IPython console, not a file. Just like an input(), but for several lines. As I understand the standard way in this case is to use sys.stdin.readlines() - but it does not work in my case.

Comment: I don't think this works in the IPython console, sorry.